# Salvar arquivo com openFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

Preciso selecionar arquivos PDF com o `openFileDialog` e salvá-los em um diretório específico definido em uma `string` em `Properties.Settings`, porém o código abaixo não funciona.

```
private void btAnexarArquivo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Displays an OpenFileDialog so the user can select a Cursor.  
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Arquivo PDF|*.pdf";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Selecione o arquivo PDF";

        // Show the Dialog.  
        // If the user clicked OK in the dialog and  
        // a .CUR file was selected, open it.  
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string diretorio = openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory;
            string destino = Properties.Settings.Default.Pasta + ticket + ".pdf";
            FileInfo oFile = new FileInfo(destino);
            if (oFile.Exists)
            {
                oFile.Delete();
            }

            // To move a file or folder to a new location:
            System.IO.File.Copy(diretorio, destino);
        }  
    }
```

Apresenta o seguinte erro:

[image: Código de Erro]

O que faço pra corrigir?

Comment: Como está o resultado das variáveis `diretorio` e `destino`, poderia postar por favor?

Comment: A variável `diretorio` eu pego à partir de `openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory;` Acredito que ai está o erro, e a `destino` seria como exemplo: `\\192.168.10.116\MarcaBus\Arquivos\Comprovantes\arquivo.pdf`

Comment: Troque `openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory;` para `openFileDialog1.FileName;`

Comment: O problema está nesta linha penFileDialog1.InitialDirectory, tem de ser FileName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimente desta forma:

```
using System.IO;

private void btAnexarArquivo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog()
    {
        Filter = "Arquivo PDF|*.pdf",
        Title = "Selecione o arquivo PDF"
    };

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string destino = Path.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.Pasta, ticket + ".pdf");

        if (File.Exists(destino))
            File.Delete(destino);

        File.Copy(openFileDialog1.FileName, destino);
    }
}
```

Otimizei um pouco o seu código :)

O problema estava na propriedade `InitialDirectory`, que deveria ser `FileName`.

Comment: A linha `string destino = Path.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.Pasta, $"{ticket}.pdf");` está com erro no `$"{ticket}.pdf"`

Comment: É, a interpolação de strings com "$" apenas está disponível a partir da .NET Framework 4.6 se não estou em erro. Resposta editada.

Comment: `O acesso ao caminho '\\192.168.10.116\MarcaBus\Arquivos\Comprovantes\6tm2uicqky.pdf' foi negado.` Agora o erro está nas permissões, certo?

Comment: Sim, aí já será permissões.

Comment: Tem alguma forma de solucionar? Eu configurei o diretório como Writable pelo Webmin

Comment: Se executar o Visual Studio ou o EXE como Administrador, não consegue ultrapassar o problema?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88053/discussion-between-marlon-leandro-and-joao-martins).

Answer (score 1):

A classe `OpenFileDialog` possui uma propriedade que se chama `FileName`, nela contém o diretório completo + o nome do arquivo selecionado.

Altere seu código para utilizar o `FileName` ao invés do `InitialDirectory`, na declaração da variável `diretorio`:

```
string diretorio = openFileDialog1.FileName;
```